# Adcolony Unity Failed to re-package resources

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, adcolony

Try to compile with adcolony, and got this
changed manifest target sdk to 23 in unity project because adcolony has.
First time it compiled, but now it dont want.
Also, i use vuforia
can it be conflict of manifests?

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources.
D:\android-sdk\build-tools\25.0.0\aapt.exe package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J gen -M AndroidManifest.xml -S "res" -I "D:/android-sdk\platforms\android-23\android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_ --extra-packages com.adcolony.unityplugin:android.support.graphics.drawable.animated:android.support.v7.appcompat:com.google.firebase:com.google.android.gms.ads.impl:com.google.android.gms.ads:com.google.android.gms.base:com.google.android.gms:com.google.android.gms.tasks:android.support.v4:android.support.graphics.drawable -S "D:\Salavat work\Projects\Backups\ZombieARign\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\animated-vector-drawable-23.4.0\res" -S "D:\Salavat work\Projects\Backups\ZombieARign\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res" -S "D:\Salavat work\Projects\Backups\ZombieARign\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\firebase-common-9.0.1\res" -S "D:\Salavat work\Projects\Backups\ZombieARign\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-ads-9.0.1\res" -S "D:\Salavat work\Projects\Backups\ZombieARign\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-ads-lite-9.0.1\res" -S "D:\Salavat work\Projects\Backups\ZombieARign\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-base-9.0.1\res" -S "D:\Salavat work\Projects\Backups\ZombieARign\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-basement-9.0.1\res" -S "D:\Salavat work\Projects\Backups\ZombieARign\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\play-services-tasks-9.0.1\res" -S "D:\Salavat work\Projects\Backups\ZombieARign\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\support-v4-23.4.0\res" -S "D:\Salavat work\Projects\Backups\ZombieARign\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\support-vector-drawable-23.4.0\res"

stderr[
D:\Salavat work\Projects\Backups\ZombieARign\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\abc_alert_dialog_button_bar_material.xml:18: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layoutDirection from <android.support.v7.widget.ButtonBarLayout>
D:\Salavat work\Projects\Backups\ZombieARign\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\abc_alert_dialog_button_bar_material.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.irokez.zombiear:layout/abc_alert_dialog_button_bar_material for configuration v17.
D:\Salavat work\Projects\Backups\ZombieARign\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\abc_alert_dialog_material.xml:48: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:textAlignment from <android.support.v7.widget.DialogTitle>
D:\Salavat work\Projects\Backups\ZombieARign\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\abc_alert_dialog_material.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.irokez.zombiear:layout/abc_alert_dialog_material for configuration v17.
D:\Salavat work\Projects\Backups\ZombieARign\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\abc_dialog_title_material.xml:29: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:textAlignment from <TextView>
D:\Salavat work\Projects\Backups\ZombieARign\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\abc_dialog_title_material.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.irokez.zombiear:layout/abc_dialog_title_material for configuration v17.
D:\Salavat work\Projects\Backups\ZombieARign\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\abc_screen_toolbar.xml:27: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:touchscreenBlocksFocus from <android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer>
D:\Salavat work\Projects\Backups\ZombieARign\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\abc_screen_toolbar.xml: note: using v21 attributes; synthesizing resource com.irokez.zombiear:layout/abc_screen_toolbar for configuration v21.
D:\Salavat work\Projects\Backups\ZombieARign\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\abc_search_view.xml:47: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layoutDirection from <LinearLayout>
D:\Salavat work\Projects\Backups\ZombieARign\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\abc_search_view.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.irokez.zombiear:layout/abc_search_view for configuration v17.
D:\Salavat work\Projects\Backups\ZombieARign\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\notification_template_big_media.xml:42: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layoutDirection from <LinearLayout>
D:\Salavat work\Projects\Backups\ZombieARign\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\notification_template_big_media.xml:34: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginStart from <include>
D:\Salavat work\Projects\Backups\ZombieARign\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\notification_template_big_media.xml:34: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_toStartOf from <include>
D:\Salavat work\Projects\Backups\ZombieARign\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\notification_template_big_media.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.irokez.zombiear:layout/notification_template_big_media for configuration v17.
D:\Salavat work\Projects\Backups\ZombieARign\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\notification_template_big_media_narrow.xml:60: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_toEndOf from <ImageView>
D:\Salavat work\Projects\Backups\ZombieARign\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\notification_template_big_media_narrow.xml:46: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_toEndOf from <LinearLayout>
D:\Salavat work\Projects\Backups\ZombieARign\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\notification_template_big_media_narrow.xml:46: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layoutDirection from <LinearLayout>
D:\Salavat work\Projects\Backups\ZombieARign\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\notification_template_big_media_narrow.xml:38: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginStart from <include>
D:\Salavat work\Projects\Backups\ZombieARign\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\notification_template_big_media_narrow.xml:38: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_toStartOf from <include>
D:\Salavat work\Projects\Backups\ZombieARign\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\notification_template_big_media_narrow.xml:30: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_alignParentEnd from <include>
D:\Salavat work\Projects\Backups\ZombieARign\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\notification_template_big_media_narrow.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.irokez.zombiear:layout/notification_template_big_media_narrow for configuration v17.
D:\Salavat work\Projects\Backups\ZombieARign\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\notification_template_lines.xml:18: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:paddingEnd from <LinearLayout>
D:\Salavat work\Projects\Backups\ZombieARign\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\notification_template_lines.xml:77: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginStart from <LinearLayout>
D:\Salavat work\Projects\Backups\ZombieARign\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\notification_template_lines.xml:96: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:paddingStart from <TextView>
D:\Salavat work\Projects\Backups\ZombieARign\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\notification_template_lines.xml:64: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginStart from <TextView>
D:\Salavat work\Projects\Backups\ZombieARign\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\notification_template_lines.xml:27: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginStart from <LinearLayout>
D:\Salavat work\Projects\Backups\ZombieARign\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\notification_template_lines.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.irokez.zombiear:layout/notification_template_lines for configuration v17.
D:\Salavat work\Projects\Backups\ZombieARign\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\notification_template_media.xml:43: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layout_marginEnd from <include>
D:\Salavat work\Projects\Backups\ZombieARign\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\notification_template_media.xml:33: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:layoutDirection from <LinearLayout>
D:\Salavat work\Projects\Backups\ZombieARign\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\notification_template_media.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.irokez.zombiear:layout/notification_template_media for configuration v17.
D:\Salavat work\Projects\Backups\ZombieARign\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\notification_template_part_chronometer.xml:18: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:paddingStart from <Chronometer>
D:\Salavat work\Projects\Backups\ZombieARign\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\notification_template_part_chronometer.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.irokez.zombiear:layout/notification_template_part_chronometer for configuration v17.
D:\Salavat work\Projects\Backups\ZombieARign\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\notification_template_part_time.xml:18: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:paddingStart from <DateTimeView>
D:\Salavat work\Projects\Backups\ZombieARign\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\notification_template_part_time.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.irokez.zombiear:layout/notification_template_part_time for configuration v17.
D:\Salavat work\Projects\Backups\ZombieARign\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\select_dialog_multichoice_material.xml:18: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:paddingStart from <CheckedTextView>
D:\Salavat work\Projects\Backups\ZombieARign\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\select_dialog_multichoice_material.xml:18: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:paddingEnd from <CheckedTextView>
D:\Salavat work\Projects\Backups\ZombieARign\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\select_dialog_multichoice_material.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.irokez.zombiear:layout/select_dialog_multichoice_material for configuration v17.
D:\Salavat work\Projects\Backups\ZombieARign\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\select_dialog_singlechoice_material.xml:18: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:paddingStart from <CheckedTextView>
D:\Salavat work\Projects\Backups\ZombieARign\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\select_dialog_singlechoice_material.xml:18: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:paddingEnd from <CheckedTextView>
D:\Salavat work\Projects\Backups\ZombieARign\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\layout\select_dialog_singlechoice_material.xml: note: using v17 attributes; synthesizing resource com.irokez.zombiear:layout/select_dialog_singlechoice_material for configuration v17.
D:\Salavat work\Projects\Backups\ZombieARign\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\drawable\abc_ratingbar_indicator_material.xml:23: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:tileModeX from <bitmap>
D:\Salavat work\Projects\Backups\ZombieARign\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\drawable\abc_ratingbar_indicator_material.xml: note: using v21 attributes; synthesizing resource com.irokez.zombiear:drawable/abc_ratingbar_indicator_material for configuration v21.
D:\Salavat work\Projects\Backups\ZombieARign\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\drawable\abc_ratingbar_small_material.xml:23: note: removing attribute http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android:tileModeX from <bitmap>
D:\Salavat work\Projects\Backups\ZombieARign\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\appcompat-v7-23.4.0\res\drawable\abc_ratingbar_small_material.xml: note: using v21 attributes; synthesizing resource com.irokez.zombiear:drawable/abc_ratingbar_small_material for configuration v21.
AndroidManifest.xml:34: Tag <provider> attribute authorities has invalid character '$'.
]
stdout[
Configurations:
 (default)

Files:
  AndroidManifest.xml
    Src: () AndroidManifest.xml

Resource Dirs:
Including resources from package: D:\android-sdk\platforms\android-23\android.jar
applyFileOverlay for drawable
trying overlaySet Key=common_full_open_on_phone.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_disabled.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_focused.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark_pressed.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_light.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_disabled.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_focused.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_normal.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_icon_light_pressed.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_dark.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_disabled.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_focused.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_normal.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_dark_pressed.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_light.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_light_disabled.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_light_focused.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_light_normal.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_google_signin_btn_text_light_pressed.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_ic_googleplayservices.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_icon_dark.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_icon_dark_disabled.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_icon_dark_focused.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_icon_dark_normal.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_icon_dark_pressed.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_icon_light.xml
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_icon_light_disabled.9.png
trying overlaySet Key=common_plus_signin_btn_icon_light_focused.9.png
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the actual error:

> AndroidManifest.xml:34: Tag  attribute authorities has
>   invalid character '$'.

From the log, it looks like you have included Firebase in your project (it may be added automatically by the Google play resolver plugin).

From my experience, the problem with the Firebase .aar is that it contains "placeholder" items in its manifest; these normally get replaced when building an Android app with Android studio (using Gradle), but doesn't work when using Unity (unless you're using Unity 5.5 which supports gradle).

**Solution:**
If you're not using Firebase, remove the its .aar library from your project.

**Note**:
I provide a [service for fixing Android build issues](https://www.fiverr.com/lysergide/fix-android-build-issues-in-your-unity3d-project) with Unity. In case you cannot fix the error yourself, i can advise you to contact me to get it solved.